# Azure Mobile Service Client Doesn't give access to basic info like "user name"?

Tags: c#, azure, win-universal-app

Okay, so I used the MobileServiceClient class from the Azure Mobile Service Client API to sign users into their Google and Microsoft account so that they are verified to access Azure tables to access their data, but the only information that gets return is the user's SID and access key.

This is crazy! No user first name, last name, email address.... you know... basic information that you might want to use to do something like say, "Hey, John Doe! You are not signed in!"

...or am I missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, seems you are missing something.
You can find by this link how to get user information:
[Enhanced users feature in Azure Mobile Services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2013/12/16/enhanced-users-feature-in-azure-mobile-services/)

That's done with help [getIdentities function of user object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj554220.aspx). From example on [github](https://github.com/carlosfigueira/blogsamples/tree/master/AzureMobileServices/UsersFeature) you can get code:

```
  var result = await MobileService.InvokeApiAsync("identities", HttpMethod.Get, null);
  this.AddToDebug("API result: {0}", result);
```

Comment: I add that it is not as simple as it can be - authentication provider returns the information about the user, but every provider returns its own set of the fields. So, plus to what Alexej proposed, you may ask the authentication provider to give you something extra, using that provider mechanisms - in case of Facebook, it can be Graph API, Google API, Azure Graph API, etc.